# change multiple colors and also multiple images clicking by one by one through diff "id" using one div in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


});
```

```css
#box {

    width: 300px;

    height: 300px;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>

<ul>
    <li><a id="red" >Red</a>
    </li>

    <li><a id="orange">orange</a>
    </li>

    <li><a id="blue">Blue</a>
    </li>

    <li><a id="black">Black</a>
    </li>

    <li><a id="yellow">yellow</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify the issue. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but from what I understood-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#box").click(()=>{
$("#red").css("background-color", "red");
$("#orange").css("background-color", "orange");
$("#blue").css("background-color", "blue");
$("#black").css("background-color", "black");
$("#yellow").css("background-color", "yellow");

});

});
```

This changes colors of all the `<a>` on `div` click.
Refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fom57erk/)

Comment: hi... i just create editor for bg color and bg image i need to use this one on every divs but when i click first one its show but i click on 2nd div first editor hide and show editor on 2nd. for demo you can see this link www.odoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var box = $("#box");
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#useImage").is(":checked")) {
      box.css({
        "background-color": "none",
        "background-image": "url(" + $(this).data("image") + ")"
      });
    } else {
      box.css({
        "background-color": $(this).attr("id"),
        "background-image": "none"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box"></div>

<p><input type="checkbox" id="useImage"> Image</p>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="red" data-image="https://i.imgur.com/m0kpq2P.jpg">Red</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="orange" data-image="https://i.imgur.com/HB9BHqF.png">Orange</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="blue" data-image="https://i.imgur.com/qUdYRmF.png">Blue</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="black" data-image="https://i.imgur.com/MOkYBLj.png">Black</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="yellow" data-image="https://i.imgur.com/GWT6Rpk.png">Yellow</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Upon click of an `<a>` element, it sets the `#box` background color to the ID value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you. can i use background images with same div with diff id on clicking

Comment: @saqibafridi sure could. You can use `data-image` attribute on the links and then use `.data("image")` to get it a URL from the `<a>` to set the background image.

Comment: after selection image then i click bg color its select but its show back side of image

Comment: i am not using chevk box just clicking one by one change to image and change to background plz help me

Comment: @saqibafridi your question does not make any sense. Please edit your post and clarify the issue with more details.

Comment: thnk you for you help i just did it with background-color:none;

Comment: @saqibafridi great. Please use the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and after, you may should be able to Upvote and mark answers as the answer to your post.

Comment: hi... i just create editor for bg color and bg image i need to use this one on every divs but when i click first one its show but i click on 2nd div first editor hide and show editor on 2nd. for demo you can see this link    https://www.odoo.com/

Comment: @saqibafridi I am unable to find your example and I do not understand the comment. Please update your post with a MCVE.

Comment: soory its odoo demo website in this web site you can creat static web site in this web site they use editor for bg color and bg image for changing